# Applying for UK Tier 2 sponsored visa: If my employment ends, what are my options?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am in the process of getting a Tier 2 (company sponsorship).

What would happen if my employment or my company ends?

Particularly, will I have a grace period to look for a new job or will I have to leave immediately?

More details:

- Australian
- IT industry
- 33 y.o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would fall under reasons for [curtailing your leave](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/301513/T2_guidance_04-14.pdf). Basically you have 60 days to leave after your leave has been curtailed. From what I have read it takes around 28 days for them to curtail your leave after they have been notified by your former employer. You presumably might even have some additional time between being made redundant and your company notifying the home office.